# Xcode Reading NSDictionary / Table Sections

Tags: iphone, arrays, xcode, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have a tableView of 2 Dictionary objects with no problems

```
[tableData addObject:dictionary1];
[tableData addObject:dictionary2];
```

The problem lies in where the user clicks a row in for example the first dictionary.

for now, I have been using this :

```
NSLog(@"You Have Selected: %@", [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
```

and no matter if i click the first row in either second dictionary or the first one, It still gives me row 1.

How do I identify whether the user clicked the first row in the first one or the second one

**EDIT**

I use 2 Dictionaries to implement sections within the tableview. If this is causing the problem, may I ask for a similar method to show sections without dictionaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As James Bedford briefly describes; use indexPath.section to get your section. So if the rows are in a dictionary, and the dictionary is your section with rows, the code should be something like:

```
NSDictionary *rows = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
id row = [rows objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]];
```

The code is merely an example. Don't use it, it is not based on best practices :-)

P.S: I assumed you used the row numbers as keys..

Comment: Thanks for the help. But may I ask what does the best practices example looks like, as I am new to xcode and doesn't know much about such practices

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at indexPath.section.

Comment: Thanks!! I should have seen the documentation more throughly